# How to force ol3 map to immediately reload tiles from geoserver after a change?

Tags: openlayers, tiles

I am having a trouble with the cache of the browser, when I make changes, they don't appear until the next animation (ie zoom change ). What I want is an immediate reload of images after changes right now am using this method:

```
layer.getSource().updateParams({
  'ol3_salt': Math.random()
});
layer.getSource().setTileLoadFunction(layerZdcIntWMS.getSource().getTileLoadFunction());
layer.getSource().changed();
map.updateSize();
```

but it doesn't reload immediately 
what should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

You should force the reload of the browser cache.

In Google Chrome, you can do it:

1. on demand by pressing CTRL+F5 (instead of simply pressing F5) or,
2. permanently (in development) by checking the box "Disable cache" in the settings (press F1) of the devtools (press F12).

CTRL+F5 is also working AFAIK in other browsers.

Comment: Dear juminet , thanks for your answer but this doesn't full-fil my needs , because the user won't press F5 after each modification/update/suppression !